# Check if a cell value exists in one or more other cells / columns given that the rows correspond to each other (key cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Would any of you happen to know a formula that checks if a cell value exists in one more other columns given that the rows correspond to each other (key cell)? I'm trying to check if a phone number in one table is found in any other "phone" columns in table 2. Also see attached image. Best regard, Espen.

[image]

Comment: So what would the output be?

Comment: `countif` should be able to do the job here: `=if(countif(C3:E5, H3)>0, "phone exists", "phone doesn't exist")`

Comment: Scott Craner: 1 or 0, true/false

@JNevill: well, that would work if the two tables are sorted in the same order. However, in my case, the data for employee 2 is in the first row in table 2 and second row in table 1.

Comment: So what would go in the first cell in column I?

Comment: I see. So you only want to look at the corresponding 3 telephones of the user in the B:E table. Not any phone in the B:E.

Comment: @jnevill that's exactly right. I.e. first cell in column I should look at the phone numbers, column c, d and e, in row 2 (table to the left) since the employee numbers correspond. If any of the columns matches the phone number in column H, cell I should say give a true value.

Comment: @ScottCraner Perfect, that did it! Thanks a lot. Now I'll break your formula apart and try to understand it. Thanks again! Br, Espen.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(C:E,MATCH(G3,B:B,0),0),H3)>0
```

[image]

To refer to it by the tables:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Table1[[Phone1]:[Phone3]],MATCH([@Employee],Table1[Employee],0),0),[@Phone])>0
```

[image]